# Regularly varying distribution and its moments

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a positive random variable with distribution function $F\in\mathcal{R}_{-\alpha}$, i.e., the tail can be written as $\overline{F}(x)=x^{-\alpha}L(x)$, where $L$ is some slowly varying function. Then we know that $E[X^\delta]=\infty$ for $\delta > \alpha$. In order to prove this statement, I use some heurestics:
\begin{align*}
E[X^\delta] &= \int_0^\infty x^\delta dF(x) \\
&= -\left([x^\delta \overline{F}(x)]_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty \delta x^{\delta-1} \overline{F}(x) dx\right) \\
&= \int_0^\infty \delta x^{\delta-1}\overline{F}(x) dx \\
&= \delta \int_0^\infty \frac{x^\delta}{x^\alpha} \frac{L(x)}{x} dx
\end{align*}
Then I have argued that $L$ is dominated by any power function as it is slowly varying. And, to see $E[X^\delta]=\infty$, for $\delta >\alpha$, we have $x^{\delta-\alpha}\rightarrow\infty$. Is this a fair argumentation?